# What is the fastest way to get money in GTA San Andreas?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

There are quite some houses and clothes for sale, but I do not have any money. What is the fastest way to get money in GTA San Andreas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Running taxi missions can get you a small nest egg, which you then want to invest in the horse races - the odds of winning are pretty unrealistic.  I seem to remember it being the same odds of success regardless of the odds on the horse.

Save your game before you start, and then bet the max you can on the longest-shot horse.  If your horse wins, save, if not, reload your old save.  In a couple of runs at this you'll have enough cash to clear the rest of the game easily.

Comment: I always just used the casino, never even tried the horse races. EVER.

Comment: @Ender, I think the casino's kinda decent too (since again, the odds are nowhere near realistic), but the horse races are crazy.  You can end up with millions in a half hour or so.

Comment: I completed the game to 100% and didn't know there were horse races. Where's the bookmakers?

Comment: @ColonelPanic, that's probably better as it's own question, since I'm sure others might want to know.  Rest assured they do exist, though :)

Comment: Taxi missions are the least profitable (per time) of all missions.

Comment: How does this method differ from using cheats or even mods? "Save/load cheating" isn't good advice.

Answer (score 7):

There aren't really more ways to earn lots of money as fast as possible. The most effective is the horse race technique.

For users which don't know this trick:

```
1. Go to a horse race bet machine.
2. Save the game.
3. Place the highest possible amount as a bet on a horse.
4. If your horse wins, save. If not load the previous savegame and try again.
```

The other ways are as you said to do missions or murder drugdealers. They usually have something like 2000$ in their pocket.

Without cheating there's no other "very fast" ways to earn money.

Other optional ways to get money are:

1. Ambulance Job - Bringing people to the hospital.
2. Taxi Job - Bringing people to places they chose.
3. Killing prostitutes.
4. Get a Pimp Mobile and transport girls to and from their work zones.
5. Trucking Job - Do what truckers do.
6. Firefighter Job - 5 Firefighter missions give you like 10.000$.
7. Casino - Black Jack, etc.
8. Quarry - Clear ruble and they pay you.

Feel free to add more if I forget options to earn money.

Comment: And what are other ways? I'd like to know all the ways to earn money, not only the fast one :)

Comment: @Vik2015 I always completed missions and never worried about money. You never need to buy cars, since you can easily steal them, and to get weapons and bullets I always killed enemy gang members (which gives me the opportunity to conquer territories). Once you reach Las Venturas you can use the Casino to earn tons of money. Playing Black Jack is way more fun than betting on horses ;)

Comment: added other opportunities to earn money.

Comment: @LukasWarsitz, btw, AFAIK you can only save the game at the Safe House. So every time you bet, you have to go to your safe house, save the game, and then go back?

Comment: Yes you must go to your safe house or if you are on pc, you can use a quicksave mod. Just google for it and you will easily find one.

Comment: I usually use the Firefighter mission. It's not cheaty and it's imo a lot of fun and pretty easy ( if you start out in the middle of the city, so the later levels aren't too far spread out ). I get about 100,000 in about 15 minutes. Not the best way, but it's intended and nice way.

Answer (score 5):

[Roboi’s Food Mart Courier Mission](http://gta.wikia.com/Roboi%27s_Food_Mart_Courier_Mission) is the first thing I do when I start a new game.

It’ll get you around $10,000 each time you do it, and up to $2,000 in passive income once you’ve completed the mission once.

Answer (score 5):

If you have no problem with using cheat codes, this cheat adds full health and armour, and gives you $250,000!

> HESOYAM

Answer (score 4):

One pretty easy way is to finish all the challenges in flight school. Once that is done, a Hunter (modeled after the real life Boeing Apache Helicopter) will spawn at your air strip. When you attempt the vigilante missions you'll get $100,000 once you reach level 50 and the amount goes up for every level.

The vigilante missions mainly involves the destruction of three slow moving cars with stupid gangsters inside whilst the helicopter is armed to the teeth with a self-targeting machine gun and two unguided missiles and it is extremely durable.

It is really easy once you get used to the controls and I made **$100,000,000 [$100M]** in just *40 MINUTES!*

Try it and see for yourself.

Comment: It's not awarded for just finishing, but for finishing with **gold**. This is very difficult, especially on PC.

Comment: I used to do this when I played and didn't want to cheat. BEST method. I used to play with my brother and we would do 10 levels each on the helicopter and help eachother get gold in everything in the flight school. Also if you do lose the heli you can get a new one at the desert airfield by driving or flying back in a law enforcement car/heli.

Answer (score 2):

Two things I use to make money really quickly (other than what the other answers cover) are:

- Burglary missions, and
- Taking Gang Area

**Burglary**

If you park the van relatively near two houses/ apartment doors, you can alternate between them, as the state of a house is reset when you enter another one.

- Only steal TVs, as this nets you the most cash per item.
- Don't bother sneaking. The TV is in front of you and you get 10 seconds to leave once you've woken them up.
- Jog in, grab TV, leave, drop off TV, go to other door. Rinse and Repeat.

I've gotten upwards of $20k in a 'night' like this

**Gang Area**

Taking over gang area not only nets you a greater passive 'gang' income (next to your house), but you can pick up the money that the Ballas/Vagos drop when you kill them.

This has the added benefit of upping your skills with guns. In the harder areas (more filled colour) the enemies drop SMGs and AK-47s by the last wave - I'm usually maxed out in at least these two guns (possibly machine pistols as well) by the time I leave for San Fierro.

If you have trouble taking over area, I've got a few tips:

- **Start with the lighter-shaded areas** (mostly the industrial areas below Grove Street, but also in the shopping district (away from the residential area) and the beach in the south-west of Los Santos) The enemies will be fewer in number and usually wont get assault weapons (SMG, AK-47) on the third wave.
- **Take enemies from a distance** - if a few of them have reached a range from which they can fire at you, you'll die quickly. Try to kite them as much as possible.
- **Enemies spawn behind you** - Mostly. They always spawn along the footpaths out of your line of sight (behind the camera)

  - This includes side streets behind you as well.
  - They will also tend to stick to footpaths until they are in range of hitting you - use this as an early warning to back away.
- **Collect what you can** at the end of a wave, and face away from where you want them to spawn.

  - For most roads I tend to alternate ends to fight on, this way I can run through all the ammo/money and health/armour pickups whilst the enemies begin to spawn behind me.
- **Complete the Ambulance missions** if you feel like you just don't have enough health. It'll take around 30-40 minutes (real-time) but it completely maxes out your health bar, with an added 50% extra. Worth it for most of the game, not just gang area.

  - Try to grab armour pickups as well. you can also up armour to 150% by completing Police missions, but this isn't as useful as the Ambulance missions.
- **Switch to your other weapon, it's faster than reloading.** (Thanks Sgt. Foley) The game doesn't keep track of magazine status. If you use a gun down to 1 bullet left, and switch out and back, the magazine is reloaded. Take advantage of this. It is actually faster than reloading.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way is to steal a tank from the military base play the 'Vigilante' missions.

I earned half a million in under half an hour doing this, without cheating.

Answer (score 2):

I think this question needs answer that focuses on what is actually fast and efficient, not what is just fun or interesting way to get money.

### Missions to earn money

#### 1. Firefighter missions ($45,000 for level 12 + Fireproof CJ)

Reason why this is number one is that:

- Firetruck is available anytime in the game
- This mission is hard to fail
- Firetruck is much more durable than other mission related vehicles

To get a firetruck, just start a fire by making a car explode. However, do not shoot it to explode as this will award wanted level. Instead shoot it until it starts burning, then wait. Firetruck will arrive. This can easily be done as soon as you have any firearm.

Finishing the missions makes you fireproof forever in addition to cash reward.

#### 2. Vigilante missions ([Unlimited money](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/275649/54850) + armor increased at level 12)

This option is number two because, unlike Firefighter missions, requires unlocking Las Venturas and obtaining Rhino or Hunter to be pulled of easily. You can try this mission in any police vehicle, but police vehicles cannot be repaired at Pay'n'Spray which means you need to be a really good driver. I did not manage to pull it off with police motorbike or car.

With Hunter or Rhino, you an keep going with this mission forever - your vehicle is basically indestructible. The profit increases with each level up to infinity, but the difficulty does not - it stops increasing after level 12.

There is a glitch too. If you enter a fast food your targets will often die and you'll get the reward.

#### 3. Paramedic missions (over 9000 and increased max. health)

Unlike firefighter missions, paramedic ones are tightly bound to location of single hospital. I would recommend west Los Santos or Las Venturas locations, since they have flat terrain and simple road design.

The profit is not so big with those but still significant. However it's quite easy to accidentally run over patient and fail the mission.

#### 4. Courier missions

Every city has a store which can become your money generating asset if you pass four levels of it's respective delivery missions. They all follow the same pattern - you ride a two wheeled vehicle and throw packages into drop off coronas (red rings). You gain money for each level, about $25,000 total. Upon completion, the related business will generate up to $5,000. Quite frankly, that's not so much money compared to to missions mentioned above.

The missions are:

- **Los Santos - Roboi's Food Mart** - eat some food before this one, because you will be riding a bicycle
- **San Fierro - Hippy Shopper**
- **Las Venturas - Burger Shot**

Unless you're very skilled, always stop or decently slow your vehicle before throwing. Missing will cost you much more than you could ever gain by hurrying.

#### 5. Burglary (approx. $4,000 per night)

This one is not so efficient, or fast or easy, but it's quite fun, so if you find repetitive missions boring, this one is for you. This mission will be introduced to you during the first phase of the game. It requires specific car and can only be started after 20:00.

Few hints:

- If you're detected you can still re-enter the building and nobody will remember a thing
- If you are detected and you do not leave the building in 10 seconds, you get three wanted stars. Do not let this happen. The door leaving cut-scene counts in the time required to leave, do not leave at last second
- Obliterating/killing house's inhabitants does not prevent cops from coming, but after reentering the empty building, you no longer can be detected
- Once you grab an item, don't bother with stealth, since you will get out in time even if detected

#### 5. Pimp missions ($16,500 and you get paid for whoring if you finish)

Those are quite boring because you repeatedly visit same locations. You will be a personal driver for two prostitutes, who will share their profits with you as a reward. The gain is increased with each level. Upon completion, you get money for using prostitute's services.

It requires special [pimp car called Broadway](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Broadway) found mostly around the Los Santos airport.

### Situational options

#### Killing crack dealers (min $2,000 per corpse)

Those guys will spawn a lot arounnd Los Santos after the Dooberman mission.

[image: image description]

Each will drop at least two thousand dollars. They can defend themselves, so either take them down with a quick headshot or run into them with chainsaw.

#### Gambling (after unlocking Las Venturas)

Collecting Horseshoe collectibles increases your chances of winning a gamble. If you have collected enough of them, this is quite recommended option.

### Ways NOT to earn money

- **Killing random pedestrians** - soon, police will be after your sorry ass, not recommended
- **Taxi driver missions** - Contrary to what top answer here suggests, this is the least profitable and most boring sub-mission. It's however required for 100% completion.

Comment: It's worth noting that the highest voted answer uses taxi missions only to get "a small nest egg" in order to then "invest" in the primary goal - the horse races. Also, while Firefighting missions may be easy for returning players - I know from both my own experience and watching friends play that sometimes precise camera movements to control the water jet are needed in order to 'catch' the burning NPCs as they run away from the car.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is in a place called "*Inside Track*" - The horseracing establishments. I started with $4000 and after an hour betting I ended with $5,510,028.

Answer (score 1):

If you start at the downtown hospital, head right, then turn right at the first road, on your left-hand side you'll find an outdoor "mall" or concourse. In here, you can hide from the police helicopter, and cars cannot get at you. There's also a soda machine that you can use to heal yourself.

Run around in circles here, taking out everyone and all cops; you'll get a pile of handguns, and money from all the citizens wandering around, and if you're careful, you'll never get wasted.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Go to Los Santos Tower with a BMX
Step 2: Bike into yellow marker at the base
Step 3: Bike fast and bunny hop off the tower
Step 4: While falling, hold S to do backflips

You will get an insane stunt bonus that pays around $500 each time

Answer (score 1):

Just try to win the one million dollar prize on wheel of fortune at the four dragons casino. Hopefully you'll be lucky enough to win!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommended Black Jack, it's slow at first because you have to build up your gambling skills in a casino to get to the high end tables however here's what i did

1. Save in front of the Four Dragons Casino
2. Go in and find a Black Jack Table with the highest limit with only the dealer (if your desired Table isn't there then reload)
3. Bet as much money as you can
4. Win
5. Leave the Casino and Save

obviously if you loose you reload but you effectively double you money if you don't bet the maximum amount and i'm pretty sure one table you can bet a maximum of 10,000,000 (correct me if i'm wrong, i know there's a 1,000,000 table).

Black Jack is relatively easy to play and you are in a bit more control, more so with the results since what you bet is doubled after 1 win which 1 game can take a couple of minutes.

of cause much like other casino money gathering methods it requires luck and since the method requires a single dealer on the table (no players apart from yourself) you can get in at times, find the table you want and see that there are other players, you can still risk it with them but i choose not to.

the majority of the time spent in this is from saving/loading/looking for a table, i did this on the X-Box and from having no gambling skill took me about 20 minutes to get from ~400,000 to ~4,000,000 (i spent alot on houses and enough ammo to supply the US Military for a few years).

Answer (score 0):

You can kill drug dealers for a quick influx of cash - They drop anything up to $2k. Note however that (despite cleaning up the streets) you actually lose a point in respect for each dealer you kill. This doesn't add up to much, you can kill enemy gang members to make up for it, but just be aware.

The dealers that I know of are:

- White guys wearing white hoodies (He is mostly found around Grove Street).
- A Black guy with checked shirts. He is difficult to find though, as he looks very much like civilians.
- Another Black guy wearing a beanie and black t-shirt.

If you stand near them, they will say something like "What'cha need?", which you can respond positively or negatively. They're usually armed with a pistol, so if you plan on taking them out, do so quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to get money in GTA Sa is: Roulette, of course.
[image: Fastest way to get money]

Put your bet in 50/50 like: Red/Black, Even/Odd.

You can win 1 million dollar in 1 seconds.

Here is the one million dollar trick: If you win, save game, if you lose, don't save.

Comment: PS: If you're so unlucky that even the 1 million dollar trick above can't save you, and you in debt 1 million dollar, you can use the cheat "SZCMAWO" to avoid the debt collectors.