# Fastest way to get rich in Grand Theft Auto 4 - Episodes of Liberty city: The ballad of Gay Tony Singleplayer

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

What is the fastest way to get rich in GTA IV: TBOG SingleplayerT? What I do now, is betting on Cage matches. Is there perhaps another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Betting on and spectating cage matches is indeed the fastest way to make money.  Similar to the [OTB horse race trick in San Andreas](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/70410/13845), the best strategy is to save at the nearby safehouse before you place your bet, and then load the game if you lose.

Since you essentially can't lose, betting all of your money is the way to go.  If you've got a small nest egg of a few thousand, you can very quickly grow it into a few million with this method.

Comment: IIRC, you triple your bet when you win, so output_funds = (input_funds)*3^(number_of_rounds_of_betting) - that's pretty darn fast growth!

Answer (score 2):

Drug wars are also good. I have 13,00 bucks and got RPG, auto sniper rifle, ak47, p90, tons of grenades, auto shotgun,   And desert eagle pistol

Answer (score -1):

I do drug wars and a tactic for this is when are near drugs kill ALL people because then more ur shot when u have em the more money goes from mission shoots vital to pick up after the gun shots are over

Comment: You really have to rephrase that, it is very hard to understand.